# On my website I have a very slow page where I can find a loader that works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, google-chrome

On my website I have a very slow page and I want to add a loader that hide the page before all elements are loaded. I have tried many of them but they show the page a small amount of time before the loader appear. This occur especially on chrome, where I can find a loader without this bug?

Comment: You'll want to hard code the loader on the page, and hide everything else with CSS and use the `$(document).ready` function to show them, and hide the loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a loader that fit your needs, it do not contain the glitch at page load.

It's very easy to use, just call

```
$(function() {
    $(document).pageLoadPolisher()
});
```

For more information go to demo page:

[jQuery Page Load Polisher](http://hugorper.com/jquery-page-load-polisher/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your plugin do not have this annoying glitch.